# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 100 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file which I got from my backend. The JSON file is as follows.

```
{
    "documentTemplate": {
        "pageFormat": {
            "pageWidth": "50",
            "pageLength": "13",
            "usePageLengthFromPrinter": false
        },
        "template": {
            "header": [
                "                    Delivery Order                    ",
                "Date    : ${date}      NO.          : ${no_surat}     ",
                "Customer: ${customer}  Delivery Date: ${delivery_date}"
            ],
            "detail": [
                {
                    "table": "table_details",
                    "border": "true",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "source": "description",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "DESCRIPTION"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "do_hanwa_and_date",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "DO HW / DATE HW"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "qty",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "QTY"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "nett",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "NETT"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "gross",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "GROSS"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "size",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "SIZE"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "location",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "LOCATION"
                        },
                        {
                            "source": "urut",
                            "width": 9,
                            "caption": "URUT"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "                                   ",
                "                                   ",
                "    ___________     ___________    ",
                "    (Signature)     (Signature)    "
            ]
        }
    },
    "documentValue": {
        "date": "13-05-2019",
        "no_surat": "01024/05/DO-MARU/19JKT",
        "customer": "PT. WIJAYA STEELINDO",
        "delivery_date": "13-05-2019",
        "table_details": [
            {
                "description": "03NKBTL190205005/12",
                "do_hanwa_and_date": "46916 / 29-03-2019",
                "qty": "1",
                "nett": "4,568",
                "gross": "4,616",
                "size": "0.70MM X 151.8MM",
                "location": "PT2212",
                "urut": 64592
            },
            {
                "description": "03NKBTL190204997/04",
                "do_hanwa_and_date": "46916 / 29-03-2019",
                "qty": "1",
                "nett": "4,504",
                "gross": "4,552",
                "size": "0.70MM X 151.8MM",
                "location": "PU5111",
                "urut": 64591
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To process the data: I use Gson.

```
public class Report {

    String filePathString;
    public HashMap<String, String> convertJsonToObject() {
    
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(this.filePathString) )) {

        // Converting JSON File to Java Object
        HashMap<String, String> hashMapResult = gson.fromJson(reader, HashMap.class);
        return hashMapResult;

       } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

It's time to use the data from the GSON converter.
I use JSwing.

```
private void jButtonCompileGsonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        // Create a report, param => file`s path
        Report report = new Report(jTextFieldPathFile.getText());

        // Read the file, as the return is a hashMap
        HashMap<String, String> result = report.convertJsonToObject();


        // Get based key
        String documentTemplate = String.valueOf(result.get("documentTemplate")).replaceAll("\r?\n", "");
        String documentValue = String.valueOf(result.get("documentValue")).replaceAll("\r?\n", "");

        // Just to clarify
        System.out.println(documentTemplate);
        System.out.println(documentValue);     
        

    }
```

The result is:

```
documentTemplate => {pageFormat={pageWidth=50, pageLength=13, usePageLengthFromPrinter=false}, template={header=[                    Delivery Order                    , Date    : ${date}      NO.          : ${no_surat}     , Customer: ${customer}  Delivery Date: ${delivery_date}], detail=[{table=table_details, border=true, columns=[{source=description, width=9.0, caption=DESCRIPTION}, {source=do_hanwa_and_date, width=9.0, caption=DO HW / DATE HW}, {source=qty, width=9.0, caption=QTY}, {source=nett, width=9.0, caption=NETT}, {source=gross, width=9.0, caption=GROSS}, {source=size, width=9.0, caption=SIZE}, {source=location, width=9.0, caption=LOCATION}, {source=urut, width=9.0, caption=URUT}]},                                    ,                                    ,     ___________     ___________    ,     (Signature)     (Signature)    ]}}
documentValue    => {date=13-05-2019, no_surat=01024/05/DO-MARU/19JKT, customer=PT. WIJAYA STEELINDO, delivery_date=13-05-2019, table_details=[{description=03NKBTL190205005/12, do_hanwa_and_date=46916 / 29-03-2019, qty=1, nett=4,568, gross=4,616, size=0.70MM X 151.8MM, location=PT2212, urut=64592.0}, {description=03NKBTL190204997/04, do_hanwa_and_date=46916 / 29-03-2019, qty=1, nett=4,504, gross=4,552, size=0.70MM X 151.8MM, location=PU5111, urut=64591.0}]}
```

I use this library: [SimpleESCP](https://blog.jocki.me/simple-escp/#_data_source)

From these libraries, the interpretation is as follows.

```
import javax.json.JsonObject;
public class JsonDataSource implements DataSource {

    private static final Logger LOG;
    private JsonObject source;

    public JsonDataSource(String jsonString){
    
    }

}
```

I use it like this and get the following error message:

```
JsonDataSource jsonDataSource = new JsonDataSource(documentValue);

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 100 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1)
```

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: To me it does not look like a proper json... Validate your json in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: Sorry mate, its valid. Just try by  yourself.

Comment: See this https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serialize-deserialize-hashmap/ the gson needs the TypeToken for arrays